Relation properties
I'm studying the properties of relations. I'm struggling in getting the point for the following exercise:
Let $R$ be the relation "is strictly higher than" applied to the set of all mountain peaks. The exercise asks whether this relation is antisymmetric. The correct answer is that it is.
I understand that a relation is antisymmetric if:
\begin{equation}
x \ R \ y \ \ \text{and} \ \ y \ R \ x \implies x = y
\end{equation}
Now, if mountain A is strictly higher than mountain B, then mountain B can never be higher than mountain A. So this condition can never happen. I don't get why $x = y$.
Can you give me some intuition?

This is answered in this post. But the idea is that to prove that $p\not\Rightarrow q$ (where $p$ is $xaRy\wedge yRx$ and $q$ is $x=y$) you need to prove that $p\wedge\neg q$. However, $p$ is never true, since it cannot happen $xRy$ and $yRx$ at the same time. Thus, $p\not\Rightarrow q$ does not hold, making $p\Rightarrow q$ a true statement. Hence, the antisymmetric property is proven.
